# Design own Buck-Boost converter - Some questions

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, buck-boost

For a project of mine I would like to design my own buck-boost converter because the fixed solutions are more expensive and a bit to big for my preferences.

Vin is 12VDC - 24VDC regulated to 12VDC with ~8A max. If I take the designs from TI or RS it doesnt seem that complicated. Only a big inductance, some FETS and some capacitors.
Now what I am curious about is:

Does it need a heatsink ? If I look at predesigned once they always have big heatsinks.
If I dont want to use SMD but through hole, what kind of capacitors do I need to use ? The Datasheet or design guidelines say ceramic but in the predesigned I see electrolytic capacitors ?

Comment: If you made your max duty cycle 100% then could you do this with a buck where voltage out is say 12 and voltage in is 12 to 24 ?At your 8Amps there will be a loss due to DCR of mosfet and coil and wire .If your total resistance was say 30 milliohm then your volt loss in the special case of Vin =12 would be 240mV . Is this OK?

Comment: I thought about that too. As the valves have a good range of input voltage they could probably handle a bit of voltage drop. What about designing such a buck? Is it easy, cheap and small? Heatsink? Thanks!

Comment: You could use SMD parts .You do not need a chip .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vin is 12VDC - 24VDC regulated to 12VDC with ~8A max.

Buck boost brings extra complications, cost, and losses. So you should check if you can get away with a simple synchronous buck.

That depends mostly on the loads.

For example if the loads are a bunch of 12V input DC-DCs powering CPUs and stuff like that, these will run fine on 11.8V. If you check the datasheets, you may find out that they also run fine on 24V. Or maybe you can replace them with 12-24V input buck converters, which would solve your problem.

If the 12V load is motors, these won't care about a bit lower voltage either. They'll run fine on 24V too with PWM instead of a buck, with better efficiency.

If your 12V output doesn't need very accurate regulation, and can tolerate 11.5V, you can use a buck that is capable of high duty cycle like [LTC3851](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3851fb.pdf) or many others. So with 12V input and 99% duty cycle, it will output 11.88V minus ESR losses, which is pretty good.

Basically you have to consider the losses of the whole chain from the power supply to the load along with the cost, and if there are two DC-DC converters in series, that can be a better or worse compromise, it depends.

You could also use a buck, and a big slow MOSFET to connect the input directly if it is 12V.

> Does it need a heatsink ?

IF you manage to get 95% efficiency, that's 5W losses, split between two FETs and the inductor mostly, that could run without heatsink if the board is in the airflow of the fan that cools whatever is consuming the 100 watts of power. Without a fan, PCBs aren't good at thermal exchange with air, especially if they're horizontal and inside a box, so 5W in a small area is going to be very toasty.

To reduce the size of a switching converter it has to use a higher switching frequency, which means layout, decoupling, inductance, etc, are more critical. SMD MOSFETs aren't just for small size, they also minimize inductance. TO220 MOSFETs can be mounted on a heatsink, but they have pretty high inductance. Thus everyone is trying to cool their SMDs in various ways, some more effective than others. For example if the board is in a metal enclosure, you can use that as a heatsink, with lots of different ways to get the heat from the board to the enclosure.

> If I look at predesigned once they always have big heatsinks. If I dont want to use SMD but through hole, what kind of capacitors do I need to use ?

If you want it small it has to switch at high frequency.

So you want low inductance capacitors which means MLCCs. There is no other choice. The inductance of a chip MLCC is about 5-10x less than a leaded cap.

You will most likely need a few low-ESR organic polymer caps in parallel, with high HF ripple current capability.

Also the canned solutions will probably be much cheaper than DIY unless you do a large quantity.

Comment: I see. Thanks. That sounds way more complicated than I thought. I was thinking about using a high duty cycle buck aswell, because on the load side there are only a bunch of valves that consume 500mA each and 10. Plus some other stuff that round about to 8A max. I will look into these maybe even a canned solution. I am def. not experienced enough to design this on my own if I listen to your hints.

Comment: If it's just valves, maybe you can PWM them in inverse proportion to supply voltage so they'll run fine on 12-24V...

Comment: Oh, if you want to learn how to design this sort of high power switching converter, then it's an interesting thing to do, it is not *that* complicated, but it's very very unforgiving. However, if you want a solution that works right now, instead of a journey, then... absolutely not lol, buy it canned, pre-made, off the shelf.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is not so simple. The caps should be SMD ceramics, because they have low ESR and low inductance. The MOSFETs are usually also SMD in small package, they have good thermal conductivity, but you need multilayer PCB board (70um top/bottom layer) with lots of thermal vias that is acting like a heatsink.

Comment: Do normal caps have high ESR ? In the datasheet I usual couldn't find any information about ESR values for these.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a 100W power converter and, sadly, the buck-boost is not quite the most efficient topology of all (especially in boost mode). Most probably you have seen a four MOSFET design where the big inductor is essentially inside an H-bridge: the controller drives in synchronous buck mode (more efficient) or boost mode (less efficient) and it's actually one of the most performing type of converter without using special magnetics IIRC.

The issue is that even at 90% efficiency (quite plausible, these days you can get even better than that) you'll have to dissipate about 10W which is quite frankly a lot without heat sinks. In fact with *even bigger* converters you go back to thru hole MOSFETs simply because they can be attached to bigger heatsinks (with fans and thermal resistance measured in tenths of °C/W or less). The SMD component have the advantage that they can use the circuit board as heat sinks (with heavier copper traces and maybe aluminum cores)

As for the capacitors: you need to take care of both ESR and ESL of your caps, depending on your converter operation frequence. Most of the time you'll use a mix of electrolytic (for bulk storage) and ceramics (for bypass, high frequency response and loop compensation). Ceramics have usually trascurable ESR; electrolytic not designed for switching converters often do not declare the ESR but another similar figure of merit (the tan delta or dissipation factor). There is a formula to switch between them. By the way you can see if a capacitor is designed for switching because the simple ones are specified at 120Hz. A good compromise is the OSCON (organic electrolytic) which is an electrolytic capacitor with good ESR.

If you are switching at more than about 200-250kHz layout is *extremely critical* and the ESL of thru hole components become a problem. Do not even think of using THT ceramics unless you really have done your math.